# Удаление из строки слов начинающихся с одной и той же буквы с помощью stream API

Tags: java-stream

Вход: String "мама мыла раму поливая пол водой".

На выходе должны уйти все слова, в которых первая буква встречается всего один раз. С помощью stream api. Форма выходы любая в принципе, пусть это будет например лист.

Вывод: "мама мыла поливая пол"

рама и вода ушли, так как такая первая буква встречается всего один раз.
Помогите пожалуйста понять, как это можно сделать.

Comment: первая буква чего? "мыла", "поливая" и "пол" первая буква тоже встречается один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с задачей, исходно искал решение к задаче:

*Есть массив со словами, отсортированными по алфавиту. К примеру:
String[] mass = { "арбуз", "биржа", "бокс", "болт", "сапог", "сарай" };
Нужно получить из этого массива HashMap:
[б=[биржа, бокс, болт], c=[caпог, сарай]]
HashMap должен содержать только группы более чем из одного слова.*

Изначально думал что нужно настраивать фильтр в исходно потоке, но потом разобрался с тем, что из полученной в потоке коллекции можно делать новые потоки и к ним применять фильтр.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
 String s = "сапог сарай арбуз болт бокс биржа колбаса период";

Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))                
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length)
.reversed().
thenComparing(String::compareTo))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> String.valueOf(w.charAt(0)), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(element->element.getValue().size()>1)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue()));
```